# Same directive with different attributes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have same directive used on two different places in one .html file. I want to be able to use these two directives with different options. Here's the code that should make this requirement more clear:

```
<ul multisortable="{ stop: 'updateFirstColumn', receive: 'receiveFirstColumn' }" 
    class='connected'>
        <li ng-repeat='task in tasks.firstcolumn> {{task.title}} </li>
</ul>


<ul multisortable="{ stop: 'updateSecondColumn', receive: 'receiveSecondColumn' }" 
    class='connected'>
        <li ng-repeat='task in tasks.secondcolumn> {{task.title}} </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to create directive, which is able to recognize that, if it is called by element from first column, it should work with options defined for that element. So I should be able to distinguish it, and fetch updateFirstColumn, or updateSecondColumn, e.g, depending on whether it is called by moving items from first or second column.

In my directive, in link function I did something like this:

```
link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
   $timeout(function (){
     $scope.$watch('tasks', function(newValue, oldValue) {
         if (newValue){
              angular.element($element).multisortable({
                selectedClass: 'ui-selected',
                connectWith: '.product-backlog-column'
              })
         }   
     }, true);   
   }, 0);    
}
```

And it looks like my directive always uses only options that I pass from second element.
I can't get it to work with options from first, or from second element, depending on which one is being dragged.

Does anyone have an idea, why this is happening?
Maybe I should define separate scope within directive definition, or something like that?
I tried many things but with no luck.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

If I remove $watch and $timeout, options passed with directive work fine, but jQuery call that I'm using isn't working fine. I placed jquery plugin inside controller part in directive.

Comment: I am a beginner, I read docs, and checked examples, but obviously I'm missing something. So please, refer me to some guide, instead of down voting my question.

Comment: I just found out, that my problem is caused by $timeout. If I remove it, everything works fine, and elements get options depending on directive within which they were defined. But I need to have that $timeout, so I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: Try moving the `$timeout` call, inside the `$watch` function. Probably only *around* the jquery call.

Comment: Yoshi, no, it didn't help. Only when I remove $timeout, and leave $watch, it fetches proper options, but then I don't get jquery call working properly. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery plugin is probably doing something outside of angulars knowledge. You will have to do a $apply() to let angular know to update.

To read up on how the $apply() method works, you can find it in the docs: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply)